# Dynamic return type on a getter method defined in page manager class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've only been coding for less than 2 years even less so on C# so please go easy on me :')

So basically, I'm working on a Unity project for a mobile app development (Don't ask why we chose Unity for this)

The app consists of multiple pages and each page has a ~~~PageBehavior script attached to it, which is derived from `PageIDSystem : MonoBehavior` class.

Simplified version of the `PageIDSystem` is as follows:

```
public abstract class PageIDSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum eDisplayPage
    {
        Page1,
        Page2,
        //and so on
    }

    public eDisplayPage PageID;
}
```

And any page that inherits this class clearly will have its inherited member PageID assigned (by Unity inspector, or set on awake() call, etc)

In order to manage and centralize the movement between pages, I've implemented a singleton `PageManager` class. The manager class has the usual `GetPage(~~), GetCurrentPage(~~), SetPage(~~), etc..` methods in it.

Here is my problem. I would like to make the `GetPage(eDisplayPage pageType)` methods to output the corresponding page whose type is that specific PageIDSystem-derived class.

The ideal behavior and usage of `GetPage()` would look like this :

```
PageManager.Instance.GetPage(eDisplayPage.Page1).SomeMethodDefinedInPage1();
PageManager.Instance.GetPage(eDisplayPage.Page2).SomeOtherIdkInitializeParam("init");
```

Before I ask for how to implement this, I've tried 2 different approaches to solve this.

First is to use `dynamic` as the `GetPage()`'s output type and use `Convert.ChangeType()` method to cast page (whose type is `PageIDSystem` yet) to page specific type.

This method failed because as (per my understanding,)`dynamic` keyword deduces the return type in runtime which Unity would not allow.

Second is to define it using generic, which works. Below is basically how I implemented it:

```
public T GetPage<T>(eDisplayPage ID) where T : PageIDSystem
{
    // find page corresponding to the input ID
    return page as T;
}
```

And this works, but I'm unhappy about it because I feel like I'm repeating myself using this method. To use this method I have to feed the method the page specific class AND the pageID as input, like this:

```
PageManager.Instance.GetPage<Page1Behavior>(eDisplayPage.Page1).SomePage1Method();
//                                ^                        ^ these two info is redundant no?
```

So yeah, these are the methods I've tried so far but I was wondering if there are more elegant ways to implement this `GetPage()` function so that it works as I've described above.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `these two info is redundant no?` .. you tell us ^^ can two pages have the same type? Then no, otherwise yes ^^

Comment: @derHugo Yeah the problem is that each page is unique and hence given a unique enum value as well :') so yes, you and I both agree that it's redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say the pages are unique and each page has its own implementation, then yes, I would say the enum is completely redundant and you could just go by the type alone.

```
public T GetPage<T>() where T : PageIDSystem
{
    // find page by type
    return page as T;
}
```

And then you could simply store them all in a `Dictionary<Type, PageIDSystem` in order to simplify the lookup to

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, PageIDSystem> pages = new();

public T GetPage<T>() where T : PageIDSystem
{
    return pages.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var page) ? (T) page : null;
}
```

you could simply fill that dictionary using a loop

```
[SerializeField] List<PageIDSystem> _pages;

private void Awake()
{
    foreach(var page in _pages)
    {
        pages[page.GetType()] = page;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like this implementation! Though you need to hardcode the `pages` dictionary member variable right? (since it's `private readonly` ?). My colleague just hardcoded each and every `Get###Page()` methods. Should I convince her to switch to this method instead?

Comment: the dictionary instance itself is `readonly` but you can still simply iterate and add items to it - see update at the bottom. Whether you want to switch is up to you basically but this way I'd claim is way easier to maintain and extend! (If you have a new page all you need to do is add it to the list instead of implementing and maintaining additional method every time)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have several objects of the same type but with different IDs in your map, you can remove your ID completely and use type as a key. It will remove your "repeating".

However, the solution itself looks very weird to me. Because it looks like the way to strongly connect all the parts of the app with each other. And it will be hard to maintain such kind of software. I mean things like

```
PageManager.Instance.GetPage<Page1Behavior>(eDisplayPage.Page1).SomePage1Method();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should directly implement different page behaviour by inherit from your PageIDSystem or that it call some component that inherit from a "RefreshPage" interface.

like this:

```
public abstract class PageIDSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum eDisplayPage
    {
        Page1,
        Page2,
        //and so on
    }

    public eDisplayPage PageID;

    public abstract void Refresh();
}

public class Page1Behaviour : PageIDSystem 
{
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        // implement your method here
    }
}
```

then you can simply attach these different page behaviour onto your different page object, and simply call:

`PageManager.Instance.GetPage(eDisplayPage.Page1).Refresh();`

Usually you don't need to let page manager to know such different behaviour between different page. It should just recognize the `Refresh` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I have yet to try this method but even if it works I don't conceptually understand why it would, since the return type of `PageManager.Instance.GetPage(eDisplayPage.Page1)` is so far just `PageIDSystem` on which if you call `Refresh()` it will call the yet undefined abstract method `Refresh()` in `PageIDSystem` class. Could you explain how the compiler is able to understand which specific page class the GetPage() method is returning? Thank you :)

Comment: No, although the return type is abstract type `PageIDSystem`，your function indeed return an "instance"(or called object) like `Page1Behaviour` and others that inherited from `PageIDSystem`. When you upcasting an object (create a child class, and change its type to base class), actually you don't change it at all, but just change a recognized tag from  `Page1Behaviour` to `PageIDSystem`, so when you call `Refresh` method of your `PageIdSystem`, indeed you are calling the `Refresh` behaviour implemented in `Page1Behaviour`(since they are the same object).